# Webstorm 2018.3 lagging on mac

Tags: macos, performance, freeze, lag, webstorm

after update from webstorm 2018.1 to 2018.3 the huge lags appeared. The processor loaded only 10-25%, 2-3gb ram also not used. Why webstorm don't use more resources if it necessary?
My custom VM options...

```
# custom WebStorm VM options

-Xms1024m
-Xmx8192m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Xverify:none

-XX:ErrorFile=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_webstorm_%p.log
-XX:HeapDumpPath=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_webstorm.hprof
```

Maybe something wrong in config? mac os version: 10.11.6.
I don't understand why it happening

Comment: Did you check the per-core CPU usage? Maybe it only runs a single core. Maybe also it's optimised for current macOS, 10.11 is pretty much out of support except for security updates.

Comment: Hello, Tetsujin. Maybe you are right and webstorm don't support el capitan any more. And it optimised only for new OS. Sometimes laggs disappear, i don't know why On 2018.1 version all worded fine. How to check CPU per core usage?

Comment: Activity monitor - the individual app %cpu figures in the top section are per core values.

Comment: activity monitor -> double click to webstorm app and there when i start typing something in editor: cpu usage raise from 0.1% to 189%

Comment: i think the last webstorm has horroble optimisation for mac os 10.11

Comment: Previos WS version load processor similar but works without lags